# NU1100 the following sources were not considered

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

in my c# project which i develop in visual studio i have multiple nuget dependencies and whenever a friend of mine pushes to the repository i get the following error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1100  Unable to resolve 'Esprima (>= 3.0.4)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org. MModule C:\Users\usr\Desktop\prj\Modules\folder\MModule\MModule.csproj  1

i can always resolve such errors by updating or reinstalling at least one nuget package in the project. i feel like it has to do something with the following sentence contained in the error message:

> the following source(s) were not considered: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

which leads me to my question: why does it not consider nuget.org? imo this correlates to me "resetting" the pkg list or something by updating or reinstalling. is there any way for me to force the consideration of nuget.org?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check the package source mapping of the nuget config. If there is some source mappings, remove them. Or you can make sure there's a matching pattern for the package in question.

Take a look of the official document:

[Scenario 2 of NuGet Error NU1100](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1100#scenario-2)